# Facing Problem to installing Canvas lms production RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:initial_setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

```
rpr@Taashee:/var/canvas$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:initial_setup --trace
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: comparison of Gem::Version with String failed
/var/canvas/gems/canvas_cache/lib/canvas_cache/redis_cache_store.rb:30:in `<'
/var/canvas/gems/canvas_cache/lib/canvas_cache/redis_cache_store.rb:30:in `<module:ClassMethods>'
/var/canvas/gems/canvas_cache/lib/canvas_cache/redis_cache_store.rb:26:in `<module:RedisCacheStore>'
/var/canvas/gems/canvas_cache/lib/canvas_cache/redis_cache_store.rb:25:in `<module:CanvasCache>'
/var/canvas/gems/canvas_cache/lib/canvas_cache/redis_cache_store.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
/var/canvas/gems/canvas_cache/lib/canvas_cache.rb:21:in `require_relative'
/var/canvas/gems/canvas_cache/lib/canvas_cache.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
/var/canvas/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
/var/canvas/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
/var/canvas/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/var/canvas/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/var/canvas/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'
/var/canvas/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
/var/canvas/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
/var/canvas/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:187:in `require'
/var/canvas/config/application.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
/var/canvas/Rakefile:6:in `require'
/var/canvas/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
/var/canvas/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
/var/canvas/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
/var/canvas/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:734:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/var/canvas/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:126:in `block in load_rakefile'
/var/canvas/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:208:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/canvas/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `load_rakefile'
/var/canvas/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
/var/canvas/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:208:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/canvas/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/var/canvas/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/var/canvas/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/bin/rake:25:in `load'
/var/canvas/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/bin/rake:25:in `<main>'
```

Bundle install and also try some other way